# Close and Re-open or refresh downloaded database

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, core-data

I'm looking for a easy solution to close my database et re-open it. 
My App is using an database (CoreData) with formulas, then, when new formulas are available, my App, will download the full database and replace the actual. 
This part is working well. But, once downloaded, I'd like to refresh a TableView with the new Database. I checked on the website and internet but, I didn't find answer. 
Seems this is linked to the Persistent but not sure. 
So I tried to reset my context but, my TableView is only updated once App been closed and re opened. 
So, I'd like to know if you have time to give me an example of how to refresh or even close and re open the database. 
Thanks in advance for your support.

```
NSData *fetchedData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"u189496386:xxxxx@xxxxx.com:21/DataBase.sqlite"]];     
NSUInteger length = [fetchedData length];     
ProgressDownload.progress = 0.5f;
if(length < 1)  
{
         ContactServer.text = @"Error downloading DataBase or Network access, please check your connection"; 
}
     else
{
         ContactServer.text = @"Server contacted, download in progress";     
}           
NSString *documentsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,     NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];   

NSString *filePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"DataBase.sqlite"];
testEcriture = [fetchedData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
if(testEcriture == YES) 
    {        
     ContactServer.text = @"Database updated"; 
        ProgressDownload.progress = 1.0f;  
   }
```

Then, once back to the first view, the )viewDidLoad is executed, but it seems the content didn't changed.

```
   mesProduits = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];  
  NSEntityDescription *entityDesc = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Projector" inManagedObjectContext:context];   
       NSFetchRequest *frequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init]; 
    [frequest setEntity:entityDesc];       
     NSSortDescriptor *sortDescription = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"model" ascending:YES];    
 [frequest setSortDescriptors:@[sortDescription]];  
   NSError *error;   
  NSArray *matchingData = [context executeFetchRequest:frequest error:&error];
```

Comment: did you try reload data method of the table view after your download is complete? Like [yourTableView reloadData].

Comment: Yes, I tried, checking the content of my object, still same content. looks like my database is physically copied, but, no refresh to update my  tableview

Comment: First check if the data is actually downloaded in the core data database from the web server, once that is confirmed then inside the view controller class you need to call the same method which you are using in the first place to populate the data and then reload the table. Make sure to flush the objects from array before beginning else you will see same object twice.

Comment: Please can you show some code?

Comment: Then, once back to the first view, the )viewDidLoad is executed

Comment: This code is working when App is launched, but, not working once back from the update.

Comment: Thanks - fyi, it's easier if you edit your question and add code there.

Comment: Maybe easier now :-)

Comment: Yes, thanks.  You are downloading to DataBase.sqlite in your documents directory.  You need to update your `persistent store coordinator` to use the new database.  I've never done it, but it looks like it will involve removing the existing persistent store from the PSC, copying the new database file into place, and then adding it to the PSC.

Comment: Thanks, but the question is how to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Your managed object context has a property, persistentStoreCoordinator, which provides a reference to the persistent store coordinator underpinning the database.  The PSC accesses the persistent store to read and write the data.

So, to replace the database you would do something along these lines:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = self.context;
NSError *error = nil;
// Save the context before doing anything else.
if (![context save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Error saving context:  %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    abort();
}
// Get URL to the current database...
NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *psc = context.persistentStoreCoordinator;
NSPersistentStore *currentStore = psc.persistentStores[0];
NSURL *currentURL = currentStore.URL;
// Get URL to the new database...
NSURL *appDocs = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
NSURL *newDatabaseURL = [appDocs URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"DataBase.sqlite"];
// Disconnect from the current database...
if (![psc removePersistentStore:currentStore error:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Error removing store:  %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    abort();
}
// Replace the old database with the new, keeping a backup copy...
if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] replaceItemAtURL:currentURL withItemAtURL:newDatabaseURL backupItemName:@"DataBase.backup" options:(NSFileManagerItemReplacementUsingNewMetadataOnly | NSFileManagerItemReplacementWithoutDeletingBackupItem) resultingItemURL:nil error:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Error replacing the store:  %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    abort();
}
// Open the new database...    
NSString *failureReason = @"There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data.";
if (![psc addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:currentURL options:nil error:&error]) {
    // Report any error we got.
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    dict[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] = @"Failed to initialize the application's saved data";
    dict[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = failureReason;
    dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] = error;
    error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN" code:9999 userInfo:dict];
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    abort();
}
```

The various error cases should be properly handled, I've just logged and aborted for demonstration purposes.  Be aware that your new database must match the schema for the existing database, or you will get an error.  And obviously anything previously written to your old database is lost.

Comment: Thank you, understood the way now. Top of that, my code is working now. So, really appreciated.